# How to dispatch C# generic method call into specialized method calls

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I have the following C# class:

```
public class MyType<T>
{
   public void TryParse(string p_value)
   {
      T value ;

      Parser.TryParse(p_value, out value);

      // Do something with value
   }
}
```

The point is to call the right Parser.TryParse method, depending on the generic type T.

This uses the following static class:

```
static public class Parser
{
   static public void TryParse(string p_intput, out object p_output)
   {
      // Do something and return the right value
   }

   static public void TryParse(string p_intput, out double p_output)
   {
      // Do something and return the right value
   }

   static public void TryParse(string p_intput, out int p_output)
   {
      // Do something and return the right value
   }
}
```

I expected this to work: In the worst case, the "object" TryParse would be called. Instead, I have two compilation errors:

- CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Parser.TryParse(string, out object)' has some invalid arguments
- CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out T' to 'out object'

**Question 1:** I don't understand why this doesn't work: I can be naive, but aren't all C# objects supposed to derive from "object" ? **Why T cannot be converted to object?**

**Question 2:** **How can I dispatch a method with generic type T into the right non-generic methods** (i.e. `MyType<T>.TryParse` calling the right `Parser.TryParse` according to the right type of T) ?

### Note

The question was edited to reflect the original question intent (as written in the title: *How to dispatch C# generic method call into specialized method calls*)

Comment: To my knowledge, multiple method dispatch is only possible using the dynamic keyword in .NET 4.0 as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752523/does-new-dynamic-variable-type-in-net-4-0-solve-the-single-multiple-method-dis)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, `ref` and `out` parameters do not allow type variation. So, to pass a variable to a method expecting an `out object` parameter, that variable must be declared as `object`.

From the specification (§10.6.1.2 and §10.6.1.3)

> When a formal parameter is a reference parameter, the corresponding argument in a method invocation must consist of the keyword `ref` followed by a variable-reference (§5.3.3) of the same type as the formal parameter.
>
> When a formal parameter is an output parameter, the corresponding argument in a method invocation must consist of the keyword `out` followed by a variable-reference (§5.3.3) of the same type as the formal parameter.

See: [Why do `ref` and `out` parameters not allow type variation?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx) for some insight into why.

> Bonus question: How can I dispatch a method with generic type `T` into the right non-generic methods (i.e. `MyType<T>.TryParse` calling the right `Parser.TryParse` according to the right type of `T`)?

I'm going to turn it back around on you. Why are you doing this? If you are invoking `MyType<T>.TryParse` as, say, `MyType<int>.TryParse`, why not call `Int32.TryParse` directly? What is this extra layer buying you?

Comment: I have a generic class which contains a lot of generic code. With C++ templates, it would have worked. In C#, I'll either have to move the generic code in child classes (each one for each type, using the Int32.TryParse for Int32, for e.g., as you suggested), but having copy/pasted code seems to me somewhat wrong. Hence my attempt to have generic code here.

Comment: C# generics and C++ templates are fundamentally very different animals. Don't try to write C++ code in C#.

Comment: I know about C++ templates and C# generics being different. My problem is that once you use generics, how do you fallback using non-generic code without relying on interfaces (there is no interface for TryParse) nor reflection?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is somewhat low-tech, but I have had the same problem, where I solved it by making a `Dictionary<Type, Parser>` containing the individual parsers. I will be interested in what answers this questions bring.

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: Having to use a dictionary of types in a language supporting reflection and generics seems to me somewhat wrong. But apparently, it seems to be the only solution (unless using reflection, which is as much wrong...)

Comment: +1 Because the solution has real value (despite me not liking it... But hey, it's a language issue, and you provided a solution!)

Answer (score 2):

### Current solution

The current solution I use at work is based on dynamic dispatch, that is, the keyword dynamic as defined on C# 4.0.

The code is something like (from memory) :

```
public class Parser
{
   static public void TryParse<T>(string p_input, out T p_output)
   {
      // Because m_p is dynamic, the function to be called will
      // be resolved at runtime, after T is known...
      m_p.DoTryParse(p_input, out p_output) ;
   }

   // The dynamic keyword means every function called through
   // m_p will be resolved at runtime, at the moment of the call
   private dynamic m_p = new Parser() ;

   // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

   private void DoTryParse(string p_input, out double p_output)
   { /* Do something and return the right value */ }

   private void DoTryParse(string p_input, out int p_output)
   { /* Do something and return the right value */ }

   // etc.

   private void DoTryParse<T>(string p_input, out T p_output)
   {
      // fallback method... There are no dedicated method for T,
      // so p_output becomes the default value for T
      p_output = default(T) ;
   }
}
```

The elegant part is that it can't fail (the fallback function will be called, if none with a better signature match is found), and that it follows a simple pattern (overload the function).

Of course, the real-life, production code is somewhat different, and more complicated because, with but one public static method, I want to :

1. parse both reference objects (classes) and value objects (structs)
2. parse enums
3. parse nullable types
4. I want to offer the user the possibility to derive from Parser to offer its own overloads in addition to the default ones

But I guess the use of dynamic in the current solution is, in the end, the same thing as doing reflection as done in the original answer below. Only the "notation" changes.

Conclusion, I now have the following method :

```
public class Parser
{
   static public void TryParse<T>(string p_input, out T p_output)
   {
      // etc.
   }
}
```

which is able to parse anything, including in situations where T is not known at compile time (because the code is generic).

### Original answer

[Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221724/how-to-dispatch-c-generic-method-call-into-specialized-method-calls/5221759#5221759) was right about the first question (about the compiler errors). Still, I had no solution to my problem (dispatching from a generic method to non-generic methods according to the runtime generic type T).

I tried [LukeH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221724/how-to-dispatch-c-generic-method-call-into-specialized-method-calls/5221891#5221891), but it didn't work: The generic method is always called, no matter what (*even when removing the `out` qualifier of the second parameter*).

[Morten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221724/how-to-dispatch-c-generic-method-call-into-specialized-method-calls/5223949#5223949) is the most sane one that should works, but it doesn't make use of reflection.

So, to solve my own problem, I used reflection. This needs the rewriting of the generic TryParse method:

```
public class MyType<T>
{
   public void TryParse(string p_value)
   {
      T value = default(T);

      // search for the method using reflection
      System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Parser).GetMethod
         (
            "TryParse",
            new System.Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(T).MakeByRefType() }
         );

      if (methodInfo != null)
      {
         // the method does exist, so we can now call it
         var parameters = new object[] { p_value, value };
         methodInfo.Invoke(null, parameters);
         value = (T)parameters[1];
      }
      else
      {
         // The method does not exist. Handle that case
      }
   }
}
```

I have the source code available if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This problem intrigued me, so I did some research and found a nice thing by [Paul Madox](http://paulmaddox.net/2009/04/generic-type-parser-using-generics-c.html). This seems to do the trick.

```
   public static T SafeParseAndAssign<T>(string val) where T: new()
    {
        try
        {
            T ValOut = new T();

            MethodInfo MI = ValOut.GetType().
              GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { val.GetType() });

            return (T)MI.Invoke(ValOut, new object[] { val });
        }
        catch
        {
            // swallow exception
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```